# Zantaz's EAS exchange archive product doesn't integrate with Outlook in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, outlook, exchange

I work at a place that uses Exchange with Outlook for mail, and they also use a product from Zantaz called "EAS" which does server-side archiving of old messages.  One of the artifacts of this archival is that email attachments are missing from the archived messages when viewed in Outlook.  EAS has a client tool that plugs into Outlook that enables easy retrieval of those archived messages and their attachments, but it doesn't seem to work when installed on Windows 7.  I have no direct evidence of this, other than that it simply doesn't work on my Windows 7 machine, and some of our network support staff seem to corroborate this.  The symptom is that Outlook seems to know nothing of the existence of this EAS app.  The EAS app also has a system tray icon which *is* there and offers some minimal functionality, but the real goodness is the Outlook integration, which I sorely miss.

So, my question is this: does anyone here know whether it's possible to coerce this EAS product into working correctly in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this thread is pretty old and the OP hasn't been back since April, but here's the answer:

EAS supports Windows 7 & Outlook 2010 as of the 6.3 release which was just a month ago.  There's a little goofiness still with 64 bit Outlook but we've seen it work on occasion.

Comment: Thanks!  I am not sure my employer has upgraded, but if not I will harass them to do so!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Vista.
when you install the client on Vista the EAS Addin is not applied to Outlook.
To get around this I manually copied the EAS Addin to the Addin folder.
This may be the same under Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am a little stuck, though, since I don't know which files are the addin.  I tried to go to the COM Addins doalog and add each of the EAS client dlls I could find, but I got error messages saying that they weren't actual outlook addins.  Can you tell me specifically what you did?

Answer (score 0):

The file you're looking for is easext.ecf - just copy it to the office12/addins folder and all will be well.

Comment: I see this file is already in the Office12\ADDINS folder, but I still don't get any actual integration in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to tools->Trust Center->Add Ins, and at the bottom, choose "manage: Exchange client addins, and then hit go.  Is EAS unchecked?  Also, under help->Disabled Items, is it listed there?

We often have issues where Outlook crashes, and then disabled EAS from running.